# PHP Regex display either abc or abc xyz format

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to build regex for the expression to get values for either Boost Mobile or BoostMobile whichever is present.

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: The order matters `Boost\b` matches first. `\W*((?i)Boost\s*Mobile\b(?-i)|(?i)Boost\b(?-i)\s*)\W*` would work. Have a better answer below anyway.

Answer (score 3):

In NFA regexes, in unanchored alternation groups, the first branch matched stops the group processing, the other branches located further on the right are not checked against the string. You may read more on that at [*Alternation with The Vertical Bar or Pipe Symbol*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

So, swapping the values and simplifying the pattern you could use

```
/\b(Boost \s*Mobile|Boost)\b/i
```

*However*, the most effective way here is through using an optional group:

```
/\bBoost(?:\s*Mobile)?\b/i
        ^^          ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eB9aP4/1)

The `i` case insensitive modifier is set on the whole regex. You need not switch it on and off at the beginning/end of the pattern. Also, `\W*` can match an empty string, so your way of checking a word boundary may fail here when `\b` will work.

**Pattern details**:

- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `Boost`  - a literal substring
- `(?:\s*Mobile)?`  - an optional group matching 1 or 0 sequences of

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `Mobile` - a literal substring
- `\b` - trailing word boundary